# Problem with package in Kile and Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: packages, installing, kile, sectsty

I use Kile and at compilation I get the error message:

```
file sectsty.sty not found
```

I have downloaded the ctan package, but what do I have to do now ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Quick and dirty solution: copy the `sectsty.sty` file in the same folder than your document. More robust solution, update/upgrade your LaTeX distro. Are you using TeXlive? If yes, you should try `$ sudo tlmgr install sectsty`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to install using

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-full
```

Comment: Or manually install it [from the sources](https://www.tug.org/texlive/index.html) since TeXlive version that is embedded in Ubuntu distro is sometimes outdated.

Comment: @ebo Sure, either way will do.